# MS Access VBA - SQL to retrieve Data from Form Textbox

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

sorry i am a noobie in VBA and I have created a button in my form in MS ACCESS, which is to retrieve data from table according to my inputs in form. The Textbox is name Quotation_Ref with my coding below. The WHERE statement I would like to use my textbox input as criteria to filter out irrevant entries. But it returns Error Number: 3061 = Too few parameters. Expected 1. May I kindly as for help in my coding below? Thanks!

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlSheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim SQL As String
Dim rs1 As DAO.Recordset
Dim i As Integer

'Show user work is being performed
DoCmd.Hourglass True

'*********************************************
'              RETRIEVE DATA
'*********************************************

SQL = "SELECT Quotation_Detail.[Quotation_Ref] AS [Quotation_Ref], Quotation_Detail.[L/I] AS [L/I], Quotation_Detail.Qty AS [QTY], Quotation_Detail.[U/I] AS [U/I], Quotation_Detail.[P/N] AS [P/N], " & _
"Quotation_Detail.Description AS [Description], Quotation_Detail.MFR AS [MFR], Quotation_Detail.MFC AS [MFC], Quotation_Detail.[A/C] AS [A/C] " & _
"FROM Quotation INNER JOIN Quotation_Detail ON Quotation.[Quotation_Ref] = Quotation_Detail.[Quotation_Ref]" & _
"WHERE [Quotation].[Quotation_Ref] = Me!Quotation_Ref.Text"

'Execute query and populate recordset
Set rs1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(SQL, dbOpenSnapshot)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the value from the text box into the SQL string:

```
SQL = "SELECT Quotation_Detail.[Quotation_Ref] AS [Quotation_Ref], Quotation_Detail.[L/I] AS [L/I], Quotation_Detail.Qty AS [QTY], Quotation_Detail.[U/I] AS [U/I], Quotation_Detail.[P/N] AS [P/N], " & _
"Quotation_Detail.Description AS [Description], Quotation_Detail.MFR AS [MFR], Quotation_Detail.MFC AS [MFC], Quotation_Detail.[A/C] AS [A/C] " & _
"FROM Quotation INNER JOIN Quotation_Detail ON Quotation.[Quotation_Ref] = Quotation_Detail.[Quotation_Ref]" & _
"WHERE [Quotation].[Quotation_Ref] ='" &  Me!Quotation_Ref & "';"
```

I am assuming that `Quotation_Ref` is a text string, so I have wrapped it in single quotes - if it is numeric these are not needed. Also, you should be using the `.Value` property of the control (`.Text` is only used to grab "uncommitted" data from a control), and as this is the default property, it can be omitted.

Regards,

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have to further change my Quotation_Ref to Short Text property (it was number) in order to make it work, which is fine for me for now. Thanks again!